# Cross-compilation of 'ltrace' fails with "error: libelf.h or gelf.h not found in your system" despite it being in /usr/local/include

Tags: cross-compiling, ltrace

So I have an x86_64 arch and I need to compile for aarch64 (arm). 
I have `libelf.h` and `gelf.h` in `/usr/local/include`, which should be automatically included by gcc. I also tried exporting `CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/libelf` or using the `with-libelf` parameter of ltrace's `configure` file but I always get the same error in the title.

Any ideas? I've done similar cross-compilation before with strace successfully so I'm really struggling to understand what's wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried Install libelf-dev?